# Setting Visual Studio specific options with Scons

Tags: visual-studio, scons

Does Scons have anything like CMake source_groups, or some other way to control under what category files are shown in the solution outline of Visual Studio?

Also, how do you set variables like the vs_debugger_working_directory that are IDE specific?  Is there a way to do this in Scons?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry SCons doesn't currently have support for such.

I'd guess it wouldn't be that hard to add.
Pull Requests welcomed.

Or just file an issue on github. (put link to this SO question there as well as describing what/how it should work)